# Compute which JS selector will take priority

Tags: javascript

Is it possible in JavaScript to check which element selector would take precedence in JavaScript, given a list of selectors?

For example, if I have the following two selectors:

selA: body.app > #container

selB: #container

Is it possible to check in JS which selector “applies more” to a given element? So far I have been doing the following to check if an element matches a selector:

```
el.matches(selA)
```

But I need to know which of the two selectors has a higher precedence/priority on this specific element (el). Is this possible to compute in JS?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Whether or not a selector selects a given element is binary. The element is either selected or not; there's no such thing as an element being more or less selected. Are you asking about [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear they're asking about specificity, and just didn't know that term :)

Comment: I’m asking if two selectors are both targeting an element, how can I know programmatically which one has higher specificity?

Comment: Cool, specificity is the technically correct term and is what you're looking for, but it's not as simple as just comparing a number. I linked to more information about the topic and a pre-made JS solution in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can! The term you're looking for is the selector's "specificity". There is already a popular npm module which will compute the specificity, and also supports comparing selectors:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/specificity

For more information on how this specificity value works (why does it involve multiple numbers?) and how it's calculated, check out this awesome article:

https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/